# Can i Convert VB code to C++ code

Tags: c++, vb.net, translation

Can I convert my VB code to C++? How can I do it?

This is my VB code:

```
Dim OpenFileDialog1 As New OpenFileDialog

With OpenFileDialog1
    .CheckFileExists = True
    .ShowReadOnly = False
    .Filter = "All Files|*.*|Bitmap Files (*)|*.bmp;*.gif;*.jpg"
    .FilterIndex = 2
    If .ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
        ' Load the specified file into a PictureBox control.
        PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(.FileName)
    End If
End With
```

Comment: Yeah--you can convert it, but what environment do you have available in C++? Are you intending to target C++/CLI? MFC? Other?

Answer (score 5):

Well you can *convert* it to C++, and using a graphical library might be the easiest way to do so.

I recommend using [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/products). It is a fairly simple graphical framework which works on several platforms. We currently don't know which platform you target, however I assume you're targeting Windows since you showed an example in Visual Basic.

Typically, using Qt classes `QFileDialog` and `QPicture`, you should be able to achieve your goal quite quick.

The framework is shipped with a whole set of simple examples. One of them is **exactly** what you ask.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646829%28VS.85%29.aspx#open_file) is an MSDN-Example for an OpenFileDialog using the WinAPI.